# Batch correction in differential expression analysis

Tags: r, deseq2, differential-expression, edger, batch-effects

I have sent two sets (two batches in matter of sending for sequencing) of different samples (plasma) to small RNA-seq to Qiagen company

This is how my meta data look

```
> head(meta)
           batch group    sex
30678.009 batch2     C   Male
30678.010 batch2     C Female
30941.001 batch1     C Female
30941.002 batch1     C   Male
30941.003 batch1     C   Male
30941.004 batch1     C   Male
> tail(meta)
           batch group    sex
30941.016 batch1    LT Female
30941.017 batch1    LT   Male
30941.019 batch1    LT   Male
30941.022 batch1    LT Female
30941.023 batch1    LT   Male
30941.024 batch1    LT Female
>
```

I want to extract differentially expressed RNAs between my two groups without batch effect

I am doing this

Is this correct please?

```
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = count,
                              colData = meta,
                              design= ~ batch + group)

dds <- DESeq(dds, test="LRT", reduced=~batch)

res <- results(dds)
resultsNames(dds) 

[1] "Intercept"              "batch_batch2_vs_batch1" "group_LT_vs_C"         
>
```

Answer (score 2):

If both batches contain replicates of both groups (LT and C) then the presented code is what you should do, exactly pointed out in the vignette for the LRT: http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html#likelihood-ratio-test

Comment: Thank you. Please, what do you mean by "If both batches contain replicates of both groups (LT and C)" ? I know each sample is one independent person and we have sent samples to Qiagen in two times

Comment: It means exactly like it reads. Both batches need to contain replicates (preferably in comparable numbers) of both groups. Use `table(meta$batch, meta$group)` to see the distribution contingency table.